# UIPickerView takes up all horizontal space on iPhone, but not on iPad?

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uipickerview

I noticed something that has never been a problem before.
I did a project for iPad where I used several `UIPickerView` positioned next to each other, horizontally. Here they respect the `CGRect` frame I initialize them with, meaning placing other elements on either side of them was no problem.

Now I am trying to do this on an iPhone project and here a `UIPickerView` insists on being the only element. It sizes it self to fill the screen horizontally, with the "around" graphics.

I tried different approaches, place the `UIPickerView` inside a different view then sizing that super view, that just leads to clipping, not resizing. Another thing is that the `UIPicker` insists on being placed in the center of the screen. This basically means that when a `UIPickerView` is added to the screen, even though its single component is only 70 px wide, those 320 px of the screen is used up.

What I am trying to accomplish is to have a `UIPicker` on the right side of the screen and a button to the left of it.

Am I overlooking something obvious here? Hope someone could lend a hand, thanks in advance:)

Nothing more complicated than this:

```
UIView *container = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 250.0f, 165.0f)];

UIPickerView *picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:container.frame];
[picker setDelegate:self];
[picker setDataSource:self];
[container addSubview:picker];
```

the frame I set, is not respected. It takes up all horizontal space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried your code with the same result.

However, you can set the frame after the picker has been created and added to your container, and the new size is respected.  Here's my test case, which works for me using SDK 4.2, in the iPhone simulator:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIPickerView* pv = [[[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(160, 100, 100, 216) ] autorelease];
    pv.delegate = self;
    pv.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview: pv];

    pv.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 100, 216);
}
```

Comment: Hi Tom, you are right, I get the same result by first adding the UIPicker (UIPickerView *picker = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];) without a frame and then setting the frame after the picker has been added to a view. Thank you:)